# Enabling Virtualization (VT-x) on Ubuntu VM from Windows 10 OS

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to enable virtualization within the Ubuntu VM. I have a Windows 10 OS and I installed virtual box to run Ubuntu. I had also installed virtual box within the Ubuntu VM to run Vagrant. Now, I get the error of VT-x is not available in the Ubuntu virtual box. My question is: Is there any way to have virtualization enabled within the Ubuntu VM? I have been trying to figure for a week, but at this point, I need to know if it's even possible to do it.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Windows and your VM software. This is the place for Ubuntu OS issues. I would switch to the Windows section.

Comment: This is usually controlled by a setting in the motherboard firmware.